# Register custom validator for type without annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have the following data class:

```java
public abstract class Item {

    @NotNull
    Type getType();

    void setType(Type type);

    [...]

}
```

and corresponding subclasses for each `Type` (enum) value.
The validator should then check that for all (subtypes of) `Item` that the `Type` belongs to the given subclass.

The validator implementation would look roughly like this:

```java
boolean isValid(Item item) {
    return getImplClassFor(item.getType()).isAssignableFrom(item.getClass());
}
```

How can I register such a validator to java's default validators so that it is automatically picked up by Spring/Hibernate validator... (implementation agnostic if possible)

- spring-boot-starter-validation 2.x.x
- hibernate-validator 6.0.x
- javax.validation-api 2.1 (or later)

I cannot add any custom annotations to that class or any of it's subclasses as the datamodel is outside of my control (and generated).

**Alternatives considered:**

Manually checking the type as first action in each controller method: This is very error prone as it might be forgotten or accidentally removed. And is especially hard to do right for nested data structures.

Copy&Pasting the item class into the implementation and secretly adding an annotation: Since the datamodel is outside of my control I won't get notified if they ever change that class and my copy thus might become stale/incompatible.

**TLDR:** How do I register a `ConstraintValidator` for a class, that doesn't have any annotations.